# Extract a white with black border text in an image with a complex background

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, tesseract

I need to extract text from various screenshot with any kind of colour as background, but the text is constant and always white with black border. These are some examples:

[image]

[image]

And this is the code I'm using right now:

```
custom_config = r"--oem 3 --psm 11 -c tessedit_char_whitelist= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 '"



def preprocess_finale(im):
   im = cv2.bilateralFilter(im,5, 55,60)
   im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   _, im = cv2.threshold(im, 240, 255, 1)

   return im
```

```
img= np.array(Image.open(i))
im = preprocess_finale(img)
   
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='ita', config=custom_config)
```

But the results are still not accurate at all. How can I improve my code?

Thank you all!

Comment: "the text is constant": what do you mean ? If you know the text, why would you need to extract it ?

Comment: Try using adaptive threshold technique

Comment: @YvesDaoust Of course I meant the characteristic of the text (white text with black border). if I knew the text I would not ask help to extract it correctly, thought it was kinda explicit even if my english is not perfect

Comment: @JeruLuke Thank you for your suggestion! I've tried to follow this example 
[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-thresholding-techniques-using-opencv-set-2-adaptive-thresholding/) , but I'm getting worse results than before

Answer (score 0):

Binarize and find all white blobs with width and height in a suitable range. Then you can cluster the bounding boxes that are horizontally aligned, and sort the blobs horizontally in every cluster.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there some example that I can follow? I'm having a bit of hard time understing how to follow your advice. Thanks again

Comment: @YvesDaoustThe picture is an exemple of code? Because I need to obtain that result by coding and not just using Photoshop. Also, If you don't mind, please stop commenting my post if you don't really have nothing helpful to add. Thanks and have a nice day.